# Problema con JRLoader

Tags: java, postgresql, jasper-reports

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un reporte en `Jasper Report` con el siguiente codigo:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reportes", usuario, contraseña;
File reportDir=new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/repProd.jasper"));
JasperReport reporte= (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportDir);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, null, conexion);
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);//new java.io.File("reportePDF.pdf")
exporter.exportReport();
```

Sin embargo me genera un error en la linea de:

```
JasperReport reporte= (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(reportDir);
```

El error es el siguiente:

> El Servlet.service() para el servlet [SrvRepProd] en el contexto con
>   ruta [/Aplicacion] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó
>   una excepción] con causa raíz java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: no esta ubicando esta clase `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory`

Comment: y como hago que la ubique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas la librería `Apache Commons Logging` y añadirla a tu classpath.
Puedes encontrarla [aqui](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/)